# Pointer issues with tree class

Tags: c++, pointers, tree

Im currently having a problem trying to make a tree class. Basically it boils down to: I have a root node and a current node. Both are pointers. I set the root node equal to the current node, but when I modify the current node I am now also modifying the root node.

If I make the root node not a pointer, then the "next node" value of it isnt updated...

I've tried making the "next node" a pointer, so that it is changed in both, but that doesnt seem to be working either...

I feel like there should be a simple or obvious solution that I'm missing, but for some reason cant find it. This is my code:

[AST.cpp](http://pastebin.com/c6xwVJDU)

[node.h](http://pastebin.com/V2bQkgPV)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you calling it a "tree" class with just a single link?

In a linked list design, there is a design-time choice whether to have a dummy node at the root.  Do you waste a node in order to simplify some of the boundary cases?  I always prefer not to.  The cleanest way to avoid all the boundary problems in a linked list, without a dummy node, is to keep your current position as a `node**` rather than as a `node*`.

So start with `current=&root` and advance with `current=&(*current)->nxt` or with the more convenient:

```
node* tmp = *current;
// do other things with tmp
current = &( tmp-<nxt );
```

If you really are working with a tree structure, that same idea (work with `node**` instead of `node*` solves an even wider set of problems and avoids the need for large amounts of duplicated code.

Answer (score 0):

I think the fundamental problem here is your understanding of what a tree is.

This:

```
struct node
{
        std::string value;
        std::string dst;
        std::string src1;
        std::string src2;
        node *nxt;
};
```

is just a node in a linked list. A tree needs a node to be able to have more than one child, so at the very least start again with a list of node pointers in your struct. I'd also recommend references instead of pointers. And you probably want a tree class which contains nodes, rather than just the node, so you can write code referring to the tree. Something like

```
class Tree
{
   Node Root;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you move your current pointer to another position after adding new node, you stay on the same position as before which you shouldn't, unless you call getNext after every time you add a new node. Maybe that could be a problem. 
Also, the structure you are working o is called linked list. Every tree  node should have more than one successor. (linked list is  a tree with every node having 1 successor)

Comment: I meant adding  when your root and current aren't NULL.